# Scala regex format match result

Tags: regex, scala

I wrote a function

```
def extractMobileNumber : List[String] = {
  pattern.findAllIn(s).toList
}
```

where

```
val pattern = "[0-9]{9}".r
```

which returns List[Int]
e.g. 
Input "madam please call me at 111111111 and landline at 223322" 
output : List[111111111]

Since i am learning scala i cannot figure out how can i use pattern.replaceAllIn(s, matcher)
to return "madam please call me at **111-111-111** and landline at 223322".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  val input = "madam please call me at 111111111 and landline at 223322" :: Nil

  val phoneNumber = "(.+)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})(.+)".r

  val processed = input.map {
    case phoneNumber(prefix, p1, p2, p3, suffix) => s"$prefix$p1-$p2-$p3$suffix"
    case s => s
  }

  processed.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
madam please call me at 111-111-111 and landline at 223322
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining the other answers as an exercise in the API:

```
scala> import util.matching._
import util.matching._

scala> val s = "madam please call me at 111111111 and landline at 223322" 
s: String = madam please call me at 111111111 and landline at 223322

scala> val r = "[0-9]{9}".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = [0-9]{9}

scala> val m = r findFirstMatchIn s
m: Option[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = Some(111111111)

scala> m map (m => s"""${m.before}${m.matched grouped 3 mkString "-"}${m.after}""")
res0: Option[String] = Some(madam please call me at 111-111-111 and landline at 223322)

scala> import Regex._
import Regex._

scala> def f(m: Match) = m.matched grouped 3 mkString "-"
f: (m: scala.util.matching.Regex.Match)String

scala> r replaceAllIn (s, f _)
res1: String = madam please call me at 111-111-111 and landline at 223322
```

That's what the OP was asking about.

Just noticed the char class:

```
scala> val r = """\d{9}""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d{9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that doesn't use a regex. Group the string by 3 and make a new one with a `-` between the pieces.

```
scala> "111111111".grouped(3).mkString("-")
res18: String = 111-111-111
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however, @Eugene Solution was closed to what i was experimenting(regex). However, you sol represents elegant approach for string formatting. Simple and concise